# Define a vector space by using definitions from abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

How it is possible to considerably shorten the list of properties that define a vector space by using definitions from abstract algebra?

Comment: What definition do you have to start with? To my knowledge, vector spaces _are_ defined in abstract algebra, and hence the definition will not be shorter than it already is. Maybe you mean something else?

Comment: A definition of something like a vector space is compact only in the sense that the terms which make it up may conceal implicit information. It depends on what you are prepared to consider as basic, and what you think needs to be founded on deeper axioms.

Answer (score 4):

A vector space is a module over a division ring.

Less short?  The pair $\;(V,\Bbb F)\;$ is a vector space if $\;V\;$ is an additive (abelian) group and $\;V\;$ is a module over $\;\Bbb F\;$.

Comment: You could say over a field instead of a division ring, no? If the ring of scalars is not commutative one needs to start talking about left or right vector spaces because the non-commutativity of the scalars makes it important to mention... And it would be shorter. XD

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, it is customary, I believe, to define vector spaces as modules over division rings. That's all.

Comment: Really? I mean, I'm not trying to disagree with you, but I've only heard of vector spaces in the context of fields...

Comment: Read Hungerford's "Algebra, IV.1.1. , page 169, or Grillet's "Abstract Algebra", VIII.5, page 334 ...

Comment: Sure. We don't read the same books, but you said something correct. +1

Comment: The definition of module *already* includes the abelian group structure in the definition.

Comment: I understand how V being an abelian group shortens the definition of vector space, but can you help me understand what a module is? And what is F?

Comment: @Melanie, you can google. there are thousands of site with the  definition of this important and very basic algebraic structure.

Answer (score 2):

A $R$-module ($R$ a commutative ring with unity) is an abelian group $M$ endowed with a ring (with unity) homomorphism $R\to\mathrm{End}(M,M)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let a $K$-algebra be a ring with a homomorphism from $K$. Then a $K$-vector space $V$ is the underlying addition of a $K$-algebra $R$, together with a product $K \times V \rightarrow V$ given by restriction of the multiplication of $R$.